# Add 1 to a number in an NSString that contains characters Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am new to learning Objective-C (my first programming language!) and trying to write a little program that will add 1 to a number contained within a string.  E.g. AA1BB becomes AA2BB.
.

So far I have tried to extract the number and add 1.  Then extract the letters and add everything back together in a new string.  I have had some success but can't manage to get back to the original arrangement of the initial string.

The code I have so far gives a result of 2BB and disregards the characters before the number which is not what I am after (the result I am trying for with this example would be AA2BB).  I can't figure out why!

```
NSString* aString = @"AA1BB";

NSCharacterSet *numberCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-"]; //Creating a set of Characters object//

NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];

int someNumbers = 0;

while (![theScanner isAtEnd]) {
  // Remove Letters
  [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numberCharset
                             intoString:NULL]; 
  if ([theScanner scanInt:&someNumbers]) {}
}

NSCharacterSet *letterCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

NSScanner *letterScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];

NSString* someLetters;
while (![letterScanner isAtEnd]) {
     // Remove numbers
     [letterScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:letterCharset
                                intoString:NULL];

   if ([letterScanner scanCharactersFromSet:letterCharset intoString:&someLetters]) {}
}

++someNumbers; //adds +1 to the Number//


NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i%@", someNumbers, someLetters]; 

NSLog (@"String is now %@", newString);
```

Comment: Why not hold the component parts in a class, where each component will be easy to manipulate, and provide a method to convert to `NSString*`?

Comment: thanks @trojanfoe thats a good idea! Am still very much in the learning phase so will have to look into how to do that.  Maybe I'm trying to run before I can walk!

Comment: Not necessarily.  Learning a programming language is one thing, but learning the best way to solve problems is another.  One thing you need to learn is to use the correct data type to represent your data.  In this particular case you will have to create your own data type :)

Comment: Ah right so maybe I have approached this problem the wrong way, instead of starting with a string I should split the elements into individual data types, manipulate them and then combine the results in a string.  I was trying this route as I was trying to make this into a method that I could call inside an array based on the number of strings I put in, to save sending lots of individual messages.

Comment: Yeah don't worry about sending too many messages. Not until you know you have performance problems.  Think about making your code a pleasure to maintain.

Comment: Great thanks! knowing not to get hung up on that will definitely help in my coding journey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternative solution with Regular Expression.

It finds the range of the integer (`\\d+` is one or more digits), extracts it,  increments it and replaces the value at the given range.

```
NSString* aString = @"AA1BB";
NSRange range = [aString rangeOfString:@"\\d+" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSInteger numericValue = [aString substringWithRange:range].integerValue;
    numericValue++;
    aString = [aString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", numericValue]];

}
NSLog(@"%@", aString);
```

Comment: Amazing thanks so much @Vadian that works a treat and is way less code than mine! I will definitely look into NSRange now.  Being new to all this half the battle is knowing which Classes and Methods are best to use for a given problem.